# EJS variable check weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

When determining whether a user is logged in or not. I check for a cookie (dont know if this is the correct way to check for a logged in user).

That function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function gotCookie(){
            if($.cookie("token") == null){
                console.log("User is not logged in");
                <% var loggedIn = false %>
                <% var username = null %>
                //return 0;
            }
            if($.cookie("token") != null){
                console.log("User is logged in");
                <% var loggedIn = true %>
                //return 1;
                var user = $.cookie("username");
                <% var username = user %>
            }
        }
        gotCookie();
    });
```

And further down in my file I do this:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <%= username %> <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/myuploads">My Uploads</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a id="logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/profile"><span class="visible-sm visible-xs">Settings<span class="fui-gear"></span></span><span class="visible-md visible-lg"><span class="fui-gear"></span></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<% } if(loggedIn == false) { %>
     <form class="navbar-right">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="/login">Login</a>
         <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="/register">Register</a>
     </ul>
     </form>
 <% } %>
```

The problem im having is that the buttons for "My uploads" and "Logout" is still visible even if I successfully removed the cookie for token.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Ehh.. you can't do what you're trying to do. The server variables are evaluated at page-load, you can't modify them like that and expect EJS to pick it up. Use JavaScript to hide and show things ($().hide(), $().show())

Comment: Yeah, but when I reload the page, it should register new variables and hide the buttons, right?

Comment: No, those variables come from the server, and you can't modify those variables in client JS. You need to pass in your updated variables in `res.render` - where you should be checking the cookie.

Comment: No, I dont set those values at the server, I set them right there in <% var loggedIn = true %>

Comment: Ehh, I dont *think* you can do that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777246/interweave-ejs-and-javascript-variables-inside-tags

Comment: But that is the only code with that variable in my whole system. And it sees it as true atleast once, because it shows the buttons? I appreciate your help, and I dont say that you are wrong, just that this is what I do.

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand tymeJV is absolutely right. What you are trying to do makes no sense. Your Javascript cannot modify your template values. I suggest you view the Javascript source in your browser debugging tools. You will see that the `<% var loggedIn = false %>` parts are completely absent from your code, as they should be.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Did some extra console.log to see in terminal. Will try to use $().hide and show :) Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: hide() and show() works awesome!