# How to send a redis object from app.js to html <div>?

Tags: express

I am building a quick Express JS application. I have sent data to Redis from another application.
I did an LPUSH. I was able to do this:

```
client.lrange('stash', 0, 10, function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

My goal is to, instead of doing a console.log("..."), I want to send it to a  in my index.html.
Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: Here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var redis = require('redis');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')); //used to get image
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); //ejs, not handlebars

function index(req,res, next) {
    testController.index(req, res, next);   
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('404.html');
});

//redis stuff
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

client.lrange('stash', 0, 10, function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply); //instead of this, let's place that into a div
});
//end redis

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('My example app is now running! (3000)')
});
```

Comment: what do you mean, "send it to index.html"?

Comment: I want to send the "reply" to a <div>; I want to display this information on my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my understanding you could use `ejs` to plug in data directly into your html. The problem of course is that I don't know how `client.lrange` works but I know that express reads middleware top to bottom. If `lrange`  is pulling data you need from the `db` you can save the data to a global `var data` and on a call to the endpoint of the html you want updated; render it with `ejs`.

## create a place holder for the data

```
var data;
```

## pull the data from server and save globally

```
client.lrange('stash', 0, 10, function(err, reply) {
  data = reply;
});
```

## render html page with ejs using ejs tags

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', {reddisData: data});
});
```

## plug it into your html

```
<a>
   <%= reddisData %>
</a>
```

## all together

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

app = express()
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.set('html', 'ejs');

var data;

client.lrange('stash', 0, 10, function(err, reply) {
  data = reply;
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html', {reddisData: data});
});
```

Hope this helps, if it doesn't work for you the idea is what counts. Look into using [ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777246/interweave-ejs-and-javascript-variables-inside-tags) to resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes it helped! This was exactly what I needed, thank you!